# Does $f$ map $T$ isomorphically to $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> When $A=S_1\oplus T$ and $B=S_2\oplus T$ and $B\subset A$ and the map $\ f: A\to B$ is onto, can I deduce that $f$ carries $T$ to $T$

I don't know whether it is useful, but $S_i$'s and $T$ have different orders (both finite)

I was searching for a general law but OK;

$A=(1+p\mathbf Z_p)\big/(1+p^n\mathbf Z_p),\quad B=(1+p\mathbf Z_p)\big/(1+p^{n-1}\mathbf Z_p)$

and in this case $T=F_p^{\times}$

Comment: What are $A$ $B$, $T$... ? Abelian groups ? Can you state precisely what they are ?

Comment: Do the $S_i$ have finite order?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in general is no.  For instance, consider
$$
S_1 = \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2, \quad S_2 =\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2, \quad T = \Bbb Z_2
$$
where $\Bbb Z_2 = \Bbb Z/(2\Bbb Z)$ (the integers modulo $2$ under addition).  Define $f:S_1 \oplus T \to S_2 \oplus T$ by
$$
f((p,q,r),s) = ((p,q),r)
$$
In this case, we see that $f$ carries $T$ to $0$.  Or, take
$$
g((p,q,r),s) = ((s,p),q)
$$
which carries $T$ to a subgroup of $S_2$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $ S_1 = S_2 = T$ and define $f(x, y) = (y , x)$.

Comment: $S_i$ and $T$ cannot be equal,

Answer (score 0):

There is no general result there. The thing is, you know that there is no such result for direct sums of vector spaces, and abelian groups often behave as vector spaces (except, indeed, for torsion phenomenas). But even considering torsion, there may be several ways to see $T$ as a direct complement of $S_2$, in which case $f(T)$ could not be all of them !

Considering your precise situation, I am not sure how you can see your $T$ inside your $A$ and $B$. But I imagine that $A$ is in fact $A=\mathbf Z_p^\times/(1+p^n\mathbf Z_p)$ and $B=\mathbf Z_p^\times\big/(1+p^{n-1}\mathbf Z_p)$ ? Then you identify $T$ with the image of $(p-1)$-roots of unity ?

Comment: Yes $T=\{x:x^{p-1}=1\}$ and the notation is as followed, $U_i=1+p^i\mathbf Z_p,\ W=U_1\times T$ with $A=W/U_n$ and $B=W/U_{n-1}$. The answer should be positive for that specific case, but I don't know how

Comment: What is your $f$ ?

Comment: If $f$ it is the canonical projection, and you defined $T$ in $A$ and $B$ as begin the image of the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity by the canonical projections, then that $f(T) = T$ is obvious, isn't it ?